# how to set the login screen after the launching screen to landscape in iOS 7

Tags: ios, uiinterfaceorientation, launching-application

how to  set the login screen after the launching screen to landscape in iOS 7.

As I m getting orientation issues when App Launches in Portrait

Comment: Should the app only support landscape? If yes, then just add the landscape images to the image asset catalogue.

Comment: No the app supports for both Landscape and portrait.

Comment: Does it need to be the launching screen only or does it need to lock the whole app in landscape mode forever? You could add launch screen assets that are 90 degrees rotated for portrait.

Comment: I just need it for launching screen remaining app supports both when  rotated to any orientation

Comment: Initially my app luanches  login screen after launching the app.I need this login screen to fix to Landscape mode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you still need to support portrait inside the app you could simply rotate the assets you use for launch images 90 degrees so it always looks to be booting with the same orientation. The only thing you need to figure out for yourself is what you do with reversed portrait on iPad.